# How do I host Nuget Gallery in my own Azure website?

Tags: git, nuget, nuget-package, nugetgallery

I have `downloaded nuget gallery code` from `git clone git@github.com:NuGet/NuGetGallery.git` as mention I tried to `setup gallery in local IIS` but I failed getting error `[No relevant source lines]`

code contains all files(unnecessary also) :(

> can anyone give me link for code that I can configure and host it on my Azure website?

Comment: Can you give some details on errors? I did the same thing a year ago and i managed to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through commits history ayear ago I did these things:

1. Removed  from 
   NuGetGallery.csproj
2. Changed http://localhost/nuget to
   http://localhost:4040 in NuGetGallery.csproj
3. Added  to
   Config
4. Added folder src/NuGetGallery/App_Data/Mail